# Not Loading the value in Real Time

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, scaffold

I am using below code to get the total number of documents from the firestore collection and then store it to `int countDocument`, it does get the value accurately, but when I used to display the same value in the Flutter widget `Text Widget` which is nested in Scaffold, upon loading the screen it does not show the value, showing `null` only, only upon hot reload it shows the value on the screen.

To represent the value of `countDocument` in `Text Widget`, I did countDocument.toString()' but still it does not show the value upon initial loading of the screen

How should I resolve it?

```
void countDocuments() async {
    StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> _myDoc = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots().listen((result) {

         countDocument = result.documents.length;
         print(countDocument);


    });
```

Comment: Try using `setState()`..

Comment: How can I use `setState()` in `Text()` widget?, sorry I am new in flutter , learning daily

Comment: @MarkDavids have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `StatefulWidget`, then using `setState`, you can change the data of the `Text`:

```
  void countDocuments() async {
    StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> _myDoc = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((result) {
      setState(() {
        countDocument = result.documents.length;
      });
      print(countDocument);
    });
  }
```

`setState` will call the `build` method again with the new data. Inside the `build` method you can do the following:

```
Text(countDocument ?? "loading")
```